# Django: User administration (create, change, delete) restricted to own group

Tags: django, authentication, django-admin, authorization

I have a django application with different user roles. Depending on the roles different content is available:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  is_appadmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_appuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_someuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The same roles should be used for administration. Especially should it be possible to have one "admin" (A) per value of D to create / edit / delete user profiles but without having superuser privileges and without users of other values for D's displayed.

I tried to achieve this with the django-admin interface. As soon as user creation is allowed, these local admins can assign themselves "is_superuser".

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

role A:

- create, change and delete users of B with the same value for D
- add users C to same group of D (m:n)
- create new users C
- access to admin interface

role B + C:

- change own user profiles
- not necessarily access to admin interface

role C:

- may belong to different D

D:

- m:n relationship table used to filter data displayed

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a user admin app in addition to django-admin where users have rights depending on their roles.